# How can I select the numbering of pages in lyx?

Tags: formatting, lyx, pagestyle

I am writing my PhD thesis and I do not know how to select where the numbering of pages starts. So far, I have six pages. However, I want that the numeration starts from page 2 instead of page 1 in lyx. Is it possible ?

Comment: Write `\stepcounter{page}` in Document->Settings->Latex Preamble

Comment: I tryed your suggestion but it did not work. I am writing a Two-sided document. Is this a conflict ?

Comment: Is hard to guess why some that should work is not working without see what are you really doing, but the idea change the counter `page` in the preamble or even anywhere in the first page (ithen in a ERT box, of course). The `\setcounter` command by default just add +1 to the actual count. You can try  also some like  `\setcounter{page}{100}` to the fix the counter to 100 for instance, no matter which count was previously.

Comment: the \setcounter worked. Thanks!